# Why can't we have non-const class-level static variables?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, singleton, static-members

Why does [the Visual C++ compiler refuse to compile this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxkb76w.aspx)?

I obviously know that the error is:

> Error C2864: `Singleton<T>::p`:
>   Only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class

but **why**? (i.e. is there a **technical** reason why it is not allowed?)
Is this compiler-specific behavior or is it mandated by the standard?
It seems to be fine at the global scope, so why not at the class scope?

It also seems like [not all compilers mind this](https://www.ideone.com/MLFR6).

Also, what is the proper way of fixing this?

```
template<typename T>
struct Singleton
{
    static T *p = 0;  // Error C2864

    static T *getInstance() { /*...*/ return p; }
};
```

Comment: This special rule was introduced into the language for the sole purpose of making stupid Singleton classes extra hard to write. If you think you need a Singleton, you are wrong 99% of the time.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Wait, seriously?! How, then, do you cache the output of a static function, when you know it can't change during the lifetime of the program?

Comment: @Mehrdad: With a function-scoped static variable, probably. Or in C++11, maybe you can use `constexpr` to calculate it at compile time. What's that got to do with singletons?

Comment: @Mehrdad Don't tell me you're making a `cached_output_of_f_singleton` class. That sounds like a lot of work for something so simple.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It depends on what the value depends on and what it represents. But the short answer is, you should do whatever you would do if you had to cache more than one value from more than one source, if no source could change its value during the lifetime of the program.

Comment: The example at ideone compiles because you never instantiate the template. You'll get the same error if you do, or if you make `Singleton` a non-template class.

Comment: @spraff: How do you cache the output of a local static function if singletons are stupid?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I'm not sure, what would I do if I had to cache more than one value? I don't understand how the problem is different...

Comment: @Mehrdad: "How do you cache the output of a local static function if singletons are stupid?" With a function-scoped static variable, probably. Or in C++11, maybe you can use constexpr to calculate it at compile time. What's that got to do with singletons? (Apologies for repeating myself).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Exactly! They're not different. Yet if you had to cache more than one value, you couldn't use a singleton.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Wait, why not? Can't you just cache all of them as a single pointer to a struct?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I can't use contexpr, because it depends on the machine. And I don't even use C++11. As for the function-scoped variable, it's definitely a solution -- I just never realized it. :) Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @MikeSeymour: "What's that got to do with singletons?" -> Oh whoops, I guess I didn't answer the second part of your question. :) I guess the point isn't really to make the result *single*-instance per se, but rather to avoid doing extra work twice, for something that I only want to compute once. I guess I *could* wrap it inside something and lazy-initialize that, but it's much more annoying than just keeping a pointer to the original and doing an interlocked swap, like with a singleton.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's standard behavior. Only static const integral members can be initialized without a proper definition. All other types need to be defined somewhere, and the initialization is written at the point of definition:

```
template<typename T>
struct Singleton {
    static T *p;

    static T *getInstance() { /*...*/ return p; }
};

template<typename T>
T *Singleton<T>::p = 0;
```

Objects must be defined somewhere. If you define them within your class then its defined at a header file, and you get a different object for each compilation unit that includes it. This is relaxed for const integral types and if you don't define them then the compiler just replaces it with its literal value. Taking the address of such static const integral would still result in a linker error if no definition is provided.

Comment: Any idea **why** it's not allowed?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Because objects **must** be defined somewhere. If you define them within your class then its defined at a header file, and you get a different object for each compilation unit that includes it. This is relaxed for const integral types and if you don't define them then the compiler just replaces it with its literal value, but taking the address of such static is undefined behavior.

Comment: Huh, I never realized that issue with the header files, great point. +1

Comment: The comment and the addition to the answer are wrong in two different ways. The first one is that inside the class definition you never *define* member variables, but only *declare*. You cannot *define* a static member there *ever*. The second part that is wrong is a result from the first one: there is nothing wrong from trying to obtain the address of an integral constant static member whose value is provided in the class definition. It is a perfectly valid use of the static member and allowed.

Comment: The problem you are probably referring to is that of *failing to provide a **definition** in one single translation unit*, which is an error if the static member is used as an *lvalue*, but it is not *Undefined Behavior* either, but rather a compilation error.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You never define variables within a class definition, that's why you can't define static members either. That's exactly the point I was making. Taking the address of a static const integral member is undefined behavior, let me find you a quote from the standard.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You got that right, its undefined behavior as long as you fail to provide a definition. Are you sure its a compiler error? I believe its undefined behavior, and what actually happens is that you get different addresses in different compilation units.

Comment: @K-ballo: No, it is correct as long as you *define* the variable in one translation unit. To help you finding the quote, it is somewhere in section 3 around the *One definition rule*, and again, it is **not** Undefined Behavior --the behavior is very well defined: the implementation will reject the code and fail to link. Because the variable is *never* defined, it does not have *any* address, so no, it will not produce different addresses.

Comment: Test driver: http://www.ideone.com/mMajc The program fails because the result of the address-of operation is deferred until link time, where the linker fails to locate the definition of the static member, and triggers the error. It is tricky to write that test, as simple variants will be optimize away by the compiler (`const int *p = &test::value; cout << *p;`, for example is translated into `cout << test::value` and in turn to `cout << 0;` which does not *use* the static member at all)

Answer (score 4):

You can have this type of variable, but you cannot initialize it inside the class definition.  The only type of variable that may be initialized the way you are asking is a `static const`.

A fixed version of your class definition removes the `= 0`, and adds this below the class definition:

```
template<typename T>
T *Singleton<T>::p = 0;
```

This is standard behavior.  I'm not sure there is a *technical* reason, my guess would be it is for consistency with instance members (which cannot be initialized this way, either).  Instance variables, of course, have constructor initializer lists instead.

Answer (score 4):

As everyone pointed out, you cannot define a non-const, non-integral type in the body of a class (at least not with C++03, it changed with C++11 but I'm not sure how exactly). However, you can do it differently and clean.

```
template<typename T>
struct Singleton {
    static T* getInstance() {
        static T* p = NULL;
        /*...*/
        return p;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Declarations are meant to go into header files, where they will be compiled many times - each place they are included.

Static variables should only have one definition, so that only one copy will exist in the entire program. This means it needs to be in a source (.cpp) file. Assigning the value needs to be put at that spot.

Static constant integers are an exception to the above rules, because they can become compile time constants. When they're used, a literal value is substituted for the class member.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a non-static in the class body like that. Instead, assign the value outside the class (usually in your cpp file)

```
template<typename T>
struct Singleton {
    static T *p;

    static T *getInstance() { /*...*/ return p; }
};

template<typename T>
T *Singleton<T>::p = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The interesting question is not the one you ask, but rather the opposite:

**Why are const integral static members allowed to be assigned a value in the *declaration*?**

The important bit of the question is *declaration*. The value that a variable gets is set in the variable *definition*, and that is consistent with non-const or non-integral static members of a class, where in the class you only offer a *declaration*. The initializer value is provided in the *definition* that is outside of the class definition, commonly in a .cpp that guarantees that it will be defined in a single translation unit.

*But why can integral static constants have a value in the declaration?*

For practical reasons. The compiler can use integral constants as *compile-time* constants, that is, it can actually replace the *value* of the constant in place of the identifier in all places where the constant is used as an *rvalue*, for example when defining the size of an array. But if the *value* is only present in the definition in a single translation unit, the compiler cannot possibly use it in all other translation units. As an example:

```
// fq.h
struct fixed_queue {
   static const std::size_t max_elements; // [1]
   int data[ max_elements ];              // Error: How big is data??
};
// fq.cpp
#include "fq.h"
const std::size_t fixed_queue::max_elements = 10;
```

If `max_elements` was not allowed to have a value in the declaration [1], then you would not be able to use that constant to define the size of the array `data`, which is a quite sensible use for a static constant.

*Why not extend this to all other cases?*

Because it does not seem to make much sense... Providing the value in the class definition cannot be used by the compiler in any other circumstance, and thus it is not needed, so only integral constants need to be treated differently.

Comment: "Why not extend this to all other cases?" Java does extend it to other cases. Can someone clarify why that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that non-integral, non-const values require a memory location.

`const int` can be handled statically by the compiler and built directly into certain machine instructions, floats and more exotic objects need somewhere to live because the machine instructions will only operate in terms of their address.

In principle, the language could have allowed this, but it would mean either generating extra objects and bloating the binary (ok for consts), or making life hard for the compiler writers for non-consts: redundant copies would have to be dropped to preserve the one-definition rule (this is what template instantinations have to do, by the way).

Comment: Isn't the same thing true with globals?

Comment: Globals must be `extern` if not `const int`, which is directly analogous.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, and they also need a single definition in addition to any declarations.

Comment: The issue is that the declaration of static data members in a class definition like this *is not a definition*, so it can't have an initialiser.